# Box2D Libgdx black screen

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I am new to Box2D. I am just trying to follow a simple tutorial, but trying to integrate it inside my code:

I start creating my Libgdx game:

```
public void create() {
   float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
   float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
   camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h, 0);
   camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f, camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f);
   camera.update();
   batch = new SpriteBatch();
   viewSwitcher("GameScreen",null);
  }
```

The call to viewSwitcher, creates a new object, which creates a new Screen:

```
public GameScreenController(SomeGame t, String id) {
   somegame = t;
   db = t.getDB();
   world = new World(new Vector2(0, -20), true);
   screen = new GameScreen(this);
   [. . .]
 }
```

Inside the Game Screen (which extends Screen class) I have the render method:

```
 @Override
 public void render(float delta) {
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);  
    world.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);
    stage.act(delta);
   //stage.draw();
 }
```

Finally, a Timer, creates periodically new objects. Inside the constructor of these objects, I have the creation of the bodyDef:

```
 public void createBodyLetter() {
     BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
     bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
     bodyDef.position.set(200, 200);
     Body body = controller.getWorld().createBody(bodyDef);

     PolygonShape dynamicBox = new PolygonShape();
     dynamicBox.setAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);

     FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
     fixtureDef.shape = dynamicBox;
     fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
     fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
     body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

     dynamicBox.dispose();

}
```

The result when I start the program is just a black screen. Do anyone know where is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe, uncomment `//stage.draw();` :)

Comment: Yes I know! but the problem I want to solve is not related to drawing the stage :D!

Comment: Does it appeared the error on javaw.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize camera as

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
```

the third parameter you have given is the diamond angle which would be causing problem for you

Check the javadoc on this link
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html#OrthographicCamera(float, float, float)

Comment: Ok, now is much better! Thank you!

I read also that I cannot add simply on-the-fly new bodies, this operation should be done only BEFORE stepping the world: add body -> step the world. Do you confirm?

Comment: yes you can add bodies before or after steping the world. you can't add bodies during step cycle it will give you an native error.